# Filter only the requests with errors - Google chrome network

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How Can I filter only the requests with errors in google chrome network devtools?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found my own way to it so it's not official and other approaches may exist.

### Option 1: Filtering HTTP Status Codes

You can filter responses by their status code — [Here's a useful list](https://httpstatuses.com/) with all HTTP's Status Codes.

AFAIK this filtering feature has been working for years. It's through the `status-code` property (you can see all properties you can use [here, in Google Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#filter)).

As explained:

> `status-code`. Only show resources whose HTTP status code matches the
> specified code. DevTools populates the autocomplete dropdown menu with
> all of the status codes it has encountered.

While it's not as useful as a regex expression or a wildcard, it can narrow down a lot. For instance, if you want to see all requests with error 403, the filter is `status-code:403`.

There's a useful plot twist: you can use **negative filters**, i.e.: `-status-code:200` (notice the prepended `-` sign). That will *filter out* all requests with a 200 code, showing only, for the most part, troubled requests.

[image]

With all the 200's out of the way, you can sort the status column for a better experience.

### Option 2: Work with the HAR format

For a more in-depth analysis, almost as quick, you can easily export the whole networking log, and its details, to a HAR (**H**TTP **AR**chive) file. Right-click:

[image]

Paste it into your favorite editor. You'll see it's just a JSON file (plain text). You can always search for "error" or RegExp expressions. If you know a bit of JS, Python, etc., you can quickly parse it as you wish.

Or you can save it as `*.har` file, for instance, and use a HAR analyzer, like [Google's free analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/):

[image]

There are a [lot](https://www.google.com/search?q=analyze+har) [of tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=har+tools) that will help you analyze HAR files. Apps like Paw, Charles, and others can import HAR and show it to you as a history of requests. As far as I know, Postman doesn't understand HAR yet, but you can go to your network tab and copy in cURL format instead of HAR (or use a HAR->cURL converter like [this one](https://mattcg.github.io/har-to-curl/)) and import it right into Postman.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such functionality.
The `Filter` input doesn't apply to the `Status` column.

You can augment devtools itself by adding a checkbox in the filter bar:

1. open the network panel
2. undock devtools into a separate window
3. press the hotkey to invoke devtools - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
4. paste the following code **in this new devtools window** console and run it

```js
{
  // see the link in the notes below for a full list of request properties
  const CONDITION = r =>
    r.failed ||
    r.statusCode >= 400;
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  const input = label.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.onchange = () => {
    const view = UI.panels.network._networkLogView;
    view.removeAllNodeHighlights()
    view._filters = input.checked ? [CONDITION] : [];
    view._filterRequests();
  };
  label.append('failed');
  UI.panels.network._filterBar._filters[1]._filterElement.appendChild(label);
}
```

- You can save this code as a [snippet in devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) to run it later.
- To quickly switch docking mode in the main devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- Theoretically, it's not that hard to put this code into `resources.pak` file in Chrome application directory. There are several tools to decompile/build that file.
- The full list of internal request properties is in the [constructor of NetworkRequest](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/sdk/NetworkRequest.js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I run the script, I can see the checkbox but when it's checked I can't see the requests with errors

Comment: A request with an http status 404 for example

Comment: I've clarified the answer.